# Regex to check whether "and,or,not,and not" in a word?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a seneario where i have to check a word contains "and,or,not,and not" but the regex which i have created fails. Can any body provide me the correct regex for this?

The regex which i have created is like this

```
  Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex(@"^[not|and not|and|not]");
  if(objAlphaPattern.IsMatch(searchTerm))
  {
   //// code
  }
```

But it always returns true.

I have tried the word "Pen and Pencil" and "Pen Pencil" but both returning true.. Can anybody help in providing correct regex?

Comment: `Regex(@"(not|and not|and|not)");` should work.

Comment: Also how to check whitespace along with regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're starting with a begin anchor. If you don't want to only check if it happens at the beginning of the string then you shouldn't have the ^.

Also, you are using [] when you should be using (). Actually in this case you don't even need ().
[] indicates a character class. You just don't need that.

```
Regex objAlphaPattern = new Regex("\b(and|not)\b");
if(objAlphaPattern.IsMatch(searchTerm))
{
//// code
}
```

That should do the job.

I highly recommend [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) to help you build regex.

I also highly recommend http://www.regular-expressions.info/ as a reference.

**EDIT:**
I feel I should point out you don't really even need the object instance.

```
if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(searchTerm, "\b(and|not)\b"))
{
//// code
}
```

You can just use the static method.

That's a very good point Tim:

```
"\band\b|\bnot\b"
```

Another very good point stema:

```
"\b(and|not)\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
(not)|(and not)|(and)
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is wrong, it should be `(and|not)`. There is no need to check for `and not` either, since it will fail at the first and.

You can use an online tool to check your regular expressions; such as http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=(and|not)&input=Pen%20and%20Pencil

Comment: You should surround the parentheses with word boundary anchors `\b` so we don't match on `android` or `notepad`.